# How to do subdomain routing using Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework, hakyll

Using Hakyll that uses snap i started working on a routing server. Given the following code from their tutorials i can see the routing but i would like to have some different applications on their own subdomains like oneapp.mysite.com. Is this possible using snap or any other Haskell server?

```
site :: Snap ()
site =
    ifTop (writeBS "hello world") <|>
    route [ ("foo", writeBS "bar")
          , ("echo/:echoparam", echoHandler)
          ] <|>
    dir "static" (serveDirectory ".")
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this before, but this is what I would try:

Use the `wrapSite` function to conditionally use the routes for your subdomain and you can test which subdomain was requested with `fmap rqServerName getRequest`

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap/0.11.0/doc/html/Snap-Snaplet.html#g:7
http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap-core/0.9.2.2/doc/html/Snap-Core.html#g:5
http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap-core/0.9.2.2/doc/html/Snap-Core.html#g:10

Comment: thank you for suggestion it seem to make sense theoretically but i don't know how to use snaplets.

Comment: You don't have to use snaplets to use this.  Just use `rqServerName` and `getRequest`.

Comment: also i don't have a clue about the context in that they have to be. The most feedbacker stuff on `vhosts` is [this one](http://www.haskellshapes.com/haskell-web-programming-ii/) but it "only" emits status `ByteString` messages, any further implementation using forwarding to routes being abolished by the necessity for `vhosts` to receive an `Application`, then everything is broken. This is not in Snap, i know but is the most expressive example found out there. So, please, if you have a hint on how to do it in Snap please write a line. Or i\'m too new to Haskell. maybe

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for suggestions, i made it. I didn't used snaplets but i did use `fmap rqServerName getRequest` and the `if-then-else` statements. This is a piece of code.

```
skite :: Snap ()
skite = do
    req <- fmap rqServerName getRequest
    routes req
  where
    routes req =
        if (req == "www.site1.ro") then (site1) else pass <|>
        if (req == "site1.ro") then (site1) else pass <|>
        if (req == "www.site2.ro") then (writeBS req) else pass <|>
        if (req == "site2.ro") then (writeBS "Nowhere to be found") else pass <|>
        ifTop (writeBS req)
```

I also created a gist with the full code [here](https://gist.github.com/deckool/5011659)
For further suggestions you are welcome.